# Git merge of two commits with rename of a same file

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I was wondering how can I merge (or other action like cherry pick, rebase, ...) automatically (without manual resolving) two commits with a rename of a same file. More precisely, I've two commits which do:

- A.txt -> B.txt
- A.txt -> folder/A.txt

And I want automatically:

- A.txt -> folder/B.txt

Is it possible?

I searched solutions but I didn't find automatic ones. I tried merge, rebase, cherry pick. I tried arguments of merge strategies but it didn't work also.

Comment: Short answer is: no, there is no way to do it automatically.

Comment: This looks like an ABA question, could you please edit your question to explain why you want to do this automatically ?

Comment: @LeGEC: what's an ABA question? I've only heard of [XY Problems](https://xyproblem.info). Is it similar?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I think I got mixed up in my acronyms :) yes, that's what I was refering to

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately, *it is not possible automatically*. You change the name of a file in two incompatible ways. Git cannot possibly know which name to pick (and it definitely isn't going to "make up" a new name that it hasn't seen before).

You must manually resolve this, just like you have to manually resolve 2 changes to the same line.

Why? Let's increase the "difficulty":

1. folder/A.txt => new/B.txt
2. folder/A.txt => folder/old/C.txt

What would the result be? new/C.txt? folder/new/B.txt? folder/new/C.txt? folder/B.txt?